# Diagonalization of A $∈\ O_2$ \ $SO_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I have to following problem to solve:
Show that every matrix A $∈\ O_2$ \ $SO_2$ is diagonalizable, and determine one for A similar diagonal matrix.

What I already know: $SO_2=\{ \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -sin(\alpha) \\ \ sin(\alpha) & \ cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix} \mid \alpha\in [0,2\pi) \} $

And   $O_2
 = $$SO_2 \cup SO_2$$ \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \ 0 & \ -1 \end{pmatrix} $

I am stuck on the problem, and don't know how to do it. I already looked into my skript a couple of times now..

Comment: None of the equality $O_2=...$ looks correct. It is a set, not a single matrix. Nor is it union of $SO_2$ with itself.

Comment: Sry, my mistake I edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every matrix in $O \setminus SO$ can be written in the form
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha\\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} = \pmatrix{\cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & - \cos \alpha} 
$$
Verify that for every $\alpha$, the matrix on the right has eigenvalues $1,-1$. The rest follows.

Comment: So using Cramer's rule i get: $x_A$= $\lambda^2$-1 And with 0=$\lambda^2$-1 follows the eigenvalues 1 and -1

Comment: By "Cramer's rule", do you actually mean the definition of the determinant?  So yes, that is indeed the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, and those are the eigenvalues.  Note that our matrix is $2 \times 2$, and has $2$ **distinct** eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok. So do I need to calculate the eigenvectors now? I acutally remember a case where we had 3 distinct eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix, and the following diagonal matrix was basically the 3 distinct eigenvalues on the main  diagonal.

Comment: What you need to do depends on what "determine one for A similar diagonal matrix" is supposed to mean.

Comment: The point I was making is that with distinct eigenvalues, we can guarantee that the matrix will be diagonalizable.

Comment: My formulation is bad, sry for that. It probably means: Determine a diagonal matrix similar to A

Comment: Then you just need to put the eigenvalues on the diagonal and you're done.  No eigenvectors needed.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much :)